# Install old version of scrapyd

Tags: scrapyd

I tried various way to install old version of scrapyd but not succeed..
sudo pip install scrapyd-0.24.6
sudo apt-get install scrapyd-0.24.6
pls tell me how I can download and install scpecfic version of scrapyd

Thanks

Comment: pip install 'scrapyd==0.24.6'

Answer (score 1):

please install python packege

```
$sudo pip install scrapyd==0.24.6
```